# How can I upload video to vimeo without storing it to server in Laravel

Tags: file-upload, laravel-4, vimeo

I am using Laravel 4.2 and [vinkla/vimeo](https://github.com/vinkla/vimeo): 1.0 to upload video.

What I need is when user browse a file and click on upload I want to upload that file directly to Vimeo server.

I have configured Vinkla correctly.

When I specify the path of already uploaded file then it worked without any error

```
//Working Code
Vimeo::upload("foo.avi", false);
```

But when I try to upload file directly to vimeo

```
//Not Working
$file = Input::file('file');
Vimeo::upload($file->getRealPath(), false);
// give Error: Error completing the upload.
```

then it gives error saying

```
Error completing the upload.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've no solution for this but have you every thought of opening an issue on GitHub? You can do it here: https://github.com/vinkla/vimeo/issues/new

Comment: This should really be a comment not an answer since it doesn't have an answer in it.